# Flutter: Vertical Overflow Problems When Nesting Multiple Gridviews Inside Of Column

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, overflow

I'm having trouble with managing vertical overflow in my Flutter application.

Essentially, I have a **main column** with a **container** child that holds another **column** with **3 containers** each containing a **gridview**:

```
stateful widget
  Scaffold
    body: Center
      Column
        Container
          Column
            Container
              Gridview 
            Container
              Gridview 
            Container
              Gridview
```

**What I've Tried:**

**Method 1:**

to try and solve the vertical overflow, I have tried wrapping the **containers** in **expanded**, but the problem with that is it smushes everything together and I want all the content of the **gridviews** to be displayed at full height, with the ability to scroll down through the **main column**.

**Method 2:**

so next i tried wrapping the **main column** in a **singlechildscrollview** and removing the **expanded** wrappers from the **containers**, but that is giving me the **"vertical viewport was given unbounded height"** error.

**What I Want:**

ultimately, i want the **containers** to size automatically, to fit the content, and to be able to scroll down to view all of the content ion the **main column**.

i'm aware of the **sizedbox** solution, but again, i want the **containers** to resize automatically to fit the content inside.

what are my best options for achieving this?

**UPDATE**

these two official Flutter video explains this situation and the solution very well

https://youtu.be/ORiTTaVY6mM

https://youtu.be/LUqDNnv_dh0

it looks like what i want is to use **sliverlists** and **slivergrids** inside of a **customscrollview** instead of **gridviews** and **listviews** inside of a **column**

```
customscrollview
  slivergrid
  slivergrid
  slivergrid

NOT

column
  gridview
  gridview
  gridview
```

Comment: Can you add your full code snippet?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I can, but it's 2500 lines of repetitive widget stacking and the abstract representation i gave in my post should give you a good idea of what it looks like. let me know what i should add from my code

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html use customScrollview you can organize every part of scroll

Comment: @AlwayssBijoy this looks like the solution i need! here's official Flutter YouTube video explaining the concept https://youtu.be/LUqDNnv_dh0

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. try to wrap your [`GridView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) inside [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) Widget

```
Center(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                   maxHeight: double.infinity,
            ),
            child: GridView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                   maxHeight: double.infinity,
            ),
            child: GridView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                   maxHeight: double.infinity,
            ),
            child: GridView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Or try [**`flutter_staggered_grid_view`**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) Package hope its help to you.

Comment: ok if you see in the post i have the gridview widgets inside of containers and i have tried wrapping those containers in expanded widgets but then it smushes the content together so i have to scroll vertically inside of each gridview to see content. i want each gridview at full height to fit all the content so there is no scrolling inside of each gridview, just vertical scrolling through main column

Comment: Ok if you want scroll particular `Gridview` then set the `height` of `Container` check my updated answer and set the height on your need

Comment: as I said, i want the height of the containers to automatically adjust to the height of the content inside, so defining a fixed height for them doesn't really make sense

Comment: @XavierRenegadeAngel I have update the answer please test it I set the `constraints` for auto height of `Container`